# Upgrading to Angular 14 but my module isn't recognized anymore

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade, angular14

I have a project that I am working on it since angular 4 (I started it few years ago). I just upgrade it from 11 to 14 (one by one, 11->12, 12->13, 13->14).

I tested on angular 13 before moving to angular 14 and everything looks fine.
When I upgrading to 14, I got this error :

> Error: src/app/user/form-user/form-user.component.html:70:15 - error
> NG8002: Can't bind to 'simpleList' since it isn't a known property of
> 'app-input-text'.
>
> 1. If 'app-input-text' is an Angular component and it has 'simpleList' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'app-input-text' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.
> 3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
>
> 70               [simpleList]="['Full Time', 'Part Time', 'Casual']"
> fieldDescription="Employment Type">

App-Input-Text is my component and I declare in shared.module.ts
here is the code:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-input-text",
  templateUrl: "./input-text.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./input-text.component.css"]
})
export class InputTextComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() form: UntypedFormGroup;
  @Input() fieldName: string;
  @Input() fieldType: string; // string, date, etc
  @Input() fieldDescription: string;
  @Input() simpleList: string[]; // contains simple array of list
  @Input() buttonRightSideName: string;
  @Output() onButtonClick = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() onBlur = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() fileChange = new EventEmitter<UploadFile>();
  @Output() onButtonDownload = new EventEmitter<string>();
  @Input() isDisable = false ;
```

in shared.module.ts I declare it

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    BsDatepickerModule,
  ],
  providers: [
      AuthService,
      OrganizationService
  ],
  declarations: [
    SharedComponent, 
    AppHeaderComponent,
    CurrentOrganizationComponent,
    MyNumberPipe,
    DebounceClickDirective,
    InputTextComponent,
    AddressInputFieldComponent,
    InputListComponent,
    InputDateComponent,
    InputComponent,
    InputTextareaComponent,
    ],
  exports:[
      AppHeaderComponent,
      CurrentOrganizationComponent,
      InputTextComponent,
      AddressInputFieldComponent,
      InputListComponent,
      InputDateComponent,
      InputComponent,
      InputTextareaComponent,
      MyNumberPipe,
      DebounceClickDirective,
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

and in app.module.ts I have this

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [FormUserComponent],
    imports:[SharedModule],....
```

please tell me how to make this code work again. did I have to change my module or the way to import the components ?

thank you for your advice.

for full error codes:
https://pastebin.com/jTkPB8MX

source codes:
input-text.component.ts
https://pastebin.com/Tn0UUC5U

shared.module.ts
https://pastebin.com/PbL1jZ77

app.module.ts
https://pastebin.com/M5XRMf5D

form.user.component.ts
https://pastebin.com/QCT3Li2i

html:

```
   <app-input-text [form]="editForm" fieldName="username" fieldType="string" fieldDescription="Username">
    </app-input-text>
    <app-input-text [form]="editForm" fieldName="firstName" fieldType="string" fieldDescription="First Name">
    </app-input-text>
    <app-input-text [form]="editForm" fieldName="middleName" fieldType="string" fieldDescription="Middle Name">
    </app-input-text>
    <app-input-text [form]="editForm" fieldName="lastName" fieldType="string" fieldDescription="Last Name">
    </app-input-text>
```

Comment: In which component you were using app-input-text component?

Comment: Did you try to restart the Angular Language Service extension, or reload the vs-code?

Comment: I use app-input-text in almost all pages. I use to simplfy input form and do some checking on input